# In a MySQL Trigger, how to get informations on the user sending the request?

Tags: mysql, sql, authentication, triggers, mysql5

I'm on MySQL 5.5, with a trigger, and I want to check if the user can do its request. It's just an exemple, how can I do with a code like this?

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `database`$$

CREATE TRIGGER TBI_TEST BEFORE INSERT
ON tb_test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE ER_BAD_USER CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';

  IF NEW.host != {{HOW TO KNOW THE HOST PART OF THE CURRENT USER?}} THEN
    SIGNAL ER_BAD_USER 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'forbidden', MYSQL_ERRNO = 401;
  END IF;
END$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i've found the solution:

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user)

[EDIT]

**Warning:**

MySQL store `user` and `host` values in with UTF8-BIN collation, after lowering them and `USER()` return without lowering.

For example, `USER()` return `gqyy@MyTinnyHost-PC.local` when MySQL have stored `gqyy` and `mytinnyhost-pc.local`

a problem [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5040554/492638) ([Bug #60166](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60166)) arises when you use a `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` inside a `LOWER()` with the return of `USER()` stored in an *user-defined variable*

For example:

```
mysql> SET @user_at_host = 'gqyy@mytinyhost-PC.local';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@user_at_host, '@', -1));
+------------------------------------------------+
| LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@user_at_host, '@', -1)) |
+------------------------------------------------+
| mytinyhost-pc. ocal                            |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```