# SUBSTRING_INDEX() results "omit" character when used inside LOWER()

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I found a very strange bug in MySQL that i've reported here:

[Bug #60166](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60166)

- <strike>Can anyone confirm to me that this is a bug, and not an understanding problem of how work MySQL?</strike> (**Valeriy Kravchuk**: Thank you for the bug report. Verified just as described)
- What is the reason of this bug???
- Is there anybody to provide some advice to solve this issue other than that I described in the bug report?
- And if somebody can help me to install MySQL UDF on Windows with MySQL 5.5.8 despites the [Bug #45549](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45549), I'll will be **very** gratefull!

Anyway, in regard of the  [Bug #42404](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42404), SUBSTRING_INDEX() seems to have a very strange behavior.

Thanks by advance for any help!

**[EDIT]**

*Here, the possibles solutions already given by me in the bug report:*

> **Suggested fix:**
>
> - Use:
>
>   `mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(LOWER(@user_at_host),
>     '@', -1);`
>
>   instead of:
>
>   `mysql> SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@user_at_host,
>     '@', -1));`
> - Avoid using of this buggy function (see the more than one year old bug
>     [#42404](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42404)), and:
>
>   - Use preg_* UDF from http://www.mysqludf.org/   But
>       for now,This solution is unavailable
>       on Windows / Mysql 5.5.8 because of
>       the 8 month old [bug #45549](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45549)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select substring_index(lower(@user_at_host), '@', -1);
```

or

```
select lower(substring(@user_at_host, locate('@', @user_at_host)+1));
```

Comment: `Is there anybody to provide some advice to solve this issue **other** than that I described in the bug report?` This is the first solution I've already proposed ^^